# How do you add a custom image to your link using Branch.io?

Tags: swift, branch.io

I'm integrating Branch.io in my iOS app (swift 3) in order to enable deep linking in my app.  When sharing the branch link that is generated, I want to share an image as well, but, i'm not able to get that to work.

Below is the code.  I'm using Branch's showShareSheet to generate the link and UI.

```
static func shareAppPostLink(post: Post) {
  var branchUniversalObject = BranchUniversalObject(canonicalIdentifier: "app/\(post.id)")
  branchUniversalObject.title = " My post on this app"
  branchUniversalObject.contentDescription = "Check it out!"
  branchUniversalObject.contentIndexMode = .public
  branchUniversalObject.imageUrl = post.imageUrl
  branchUniversalObject.addMetadataKey("post_id", value: "\(post.id)")
  branchUniversalObject.showShareSheet(withShareText: "Check it out!") { (activityType, completed) in
    if (completed) {
      print(String(format: "Completed sharing!"))
    } else {
      print("Link sharing cancelled")
    }
}
```

I also did try setting the $og_image_url but that didn't seem to work.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

That should do it. Check the value of post.imageUrl and verify that it is the same as the resulting link's image url. Do this by appending "?debug=true" to the link you create and enering it into a browser's address bar (so: "https://testbed-swift.app.link/appstore?debug=true").

If the image's url is not present in the link that you create, verify that post.imageUrl is a string and not an object. If it is indeed a string, file a ticket with Branch.

Answer (score 0):

Changing "imageUrl" to "contentImageUrl" should do it.

```
branchUniversalObject.contentImageUrl = post.imageUrl
```